# Sort by Goal Conversions in Search Engine Optimization view in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Goals are my favorite functionality in Google Analytics. They let you know which traffic sources, ads, or keywords are driving signups and buying stuff and downloading your Ebook. 
You can select for goals (after you set goals up) at most views in Google Analytics, but I can't figure out how to hook goals up to Search Engine Optimization > Queries.

Is that possible? Is there another way to correlate search keyword with conversions in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is determine which keywords produce goals. It's really not possible using the SEO > queries data since these keywords are coming from Google webmaster tools which is not associated with GA data.

Comment: This isn't true. Webmaster tools is/can be hooked into GA for SEO views under Acquisition.

Comment: It can be connected - but you can't connect a goal to a query. Be sure to read the question being answered and be certain of your answer before replying.

Comment: There is a reason why they can't be connected:  The keyword data is aggregate and not connected to individual sessions.  Google is now hiding query data in the referral string from webmasters.  Referral queries now show up in analytics as [not provided](http://www.notprovidedcount.com/).